# Route 53 failover configuration

Tags: amazon-route53, aws-application-load-balancer

I have two EC2 Instances running in Same region.  One act as active and another one is passive.
Both IP’s have been added in the ALB backend pool
How do we configure in Route 53 as one Active Instance goes down another passive instance will act as a primary.

Any suggestions, how to achieve ?

Comment: You can't. Route 53 is configured to resolve to the ALB and knows nothing about EC2 failures. The ALB handles failures.

Comment: Can you use a Route53 Healthcheck and RecordSetGroups with one RecordSet being the primary and another being the secondary?